# Sending large byte stream buffer to another process

Tags: windows, service, rpc

What is the best way to send a byte stream from one Windows process to another assuming that both processes are running as a Windows service? The data consists of an image buffer. Each service is running on a separate server on the same subnet.

Should the second service that is receiving the buffer be a web service (as opposed to a Windows service), even though it will never be called on a website (just internally)?

Is RPC the best method of communicating data between two windows services? There will be a lot of data passed and performance is key.

Development language is C# 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using sockets.  RPCs have slight overhead over sockets and not worth the effort unless sending structured data.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is key then use a shared memory segment. Look up `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` on MSDN. You can start from the aptly named "Creating Named Shared Memory" available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, if you are going to use memory mapped files, then you may as well use the .net framework classes that expose the functionality. But how do you synchronize? This is one of the least convenient and most error prone IPC mechanisms. But putting all of that to one side, the question explains that the two processes are running on different machines. So MMF are no good at all.

Comment: Oops - I totally missed the "different machines" bit!